# Cохранение предыдущих значений после перезагрузки страницы django

Tags: python, html, django, post, get

У меня есть выпадающий список стран:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Код models.py:

```js
from django.db import models


class CountriesView (models.Model):

    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
```

Код views.py

```js
class IndexView(View):

    def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        countries = CountriesView.objects.all()

        context = {
            'countries': countries,
        }
        return render(request, 'index.html', context=context)

    def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):

        if request.method == 'POST':
            country = request.POST['name']

    if 'countries' in request.session:
        request.session['countries'].append(country)
    else:
        request.session['countries'] = [country]

    list_countries = request.session.get('countries', None)

    countries = CountriesView.objects.all()

    # контекст
    context = {
        'countries': countries,
        'list_countries': list_countries
    }
    return render(request, 'index.html', context=context)
```

Код html:

```html
<body>

<form method="post">
    {% csrf_token %}
    <select name="name">
        <option selected="selected">Страны</option>
        {% for country in countries %}
        <option>{{ country.name }}</option>
        {% endfor %}
    </select>
    <input type="submit" value="Вести">
</form>

{% for c in list_countries %}
    <p>{{ c }}</p>
{% endfor %}

</body>
```

Когда я выбираю страну и нажимаю на кнопку, страна пишется снизу

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Но когда я выбираю еще раз страну, то предыдущая заменяется на нынешнюю. А как сделать так, чтобы старая не исчезала, а новая писалась снизу и так далее. Как сделать так чтобы при обновлении данные сохранялись?

Comment: Храните в сессии или в GET параметре

Comment: @ZaArs, а как это осуществить через get?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
# во вью

def get(...):
    ...
    list_countries = request.session.get('countries', None)

def post(...):
    ...
    if 'countries' in request.session:
        request.session['countries'].append(country)
    else:
        request.session['countries'] = [country]
```

Comment: я исправил свой код на ваш предложенный, но у меня теперь постоянно выводится страна, которую я(после вставления вашего кода) ввел первой - Россия и + та которую я выбрал потом, но 3-я страна после выбора не добавляется, а Россия всегда выводится вне зависимости от того выбирал я ее или нет.

Comment: покажите обновленный код

Comment: я внес его уже в вопрос, посмотри в методе post

Comment: Чтобы очистить список в сессии, сделайте `request.session['countries'] = None`. Где это сделать не понятно , тк не понятна суть написания этого кода, что нужно дальше делать. Что касается, почему всегда Россия... Как вы попадаете на эту страницу

Comment: метод append заносит новую страну в сессию, но почему то ее не сохраняет в сессии и при выборе другой страны, предыдущая не сохраняется, нужно после использования метода append писать еще одну строчку request.session.modified = True, ссылка на источник https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Learn/Server-side/Django/Sessions - хорошо рассказано про сессии

Comment: можно попробовать